# Unable to align certain html elements with pure css?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am facing an issue in aligning html elements with a text. Here is my code:

```html
<div id="app">
  <input class="table" type="checkbox" style="float: left; margin-top: 5px;>">
  <div style="margin-left: 25px;"> header
    <h2></h2>
  </div>
  <div style="margin-left: 25px;">
    <input class="filter" type="checkbox" style="float: left; margin-top: 5px;">
    <h3>def</h3>
    <select style="float: left; margin-top: 5px" ;>
      <option value="p">Place</option>
      <option value="t">Time</option>
      <option value="f">Fee</option>
    </select>
    <input class="filter" type="checkbox" style="float: left; margin-top: 5px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the text `header` is placed next to a checkbox which I am able to do. But the drop down and the checkbox should be right next to the text `def`. But I am unable to do the alignment.

I tried using css properties like `float: left` and `margin-left` but that doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use inline-block property instead of float:

```html
<div style="margin-left: 25px;">
  <input class="filter" type="checkbox" style="display: inline-block; margin-top: 5px;">
  <h3 style="display: inline-block;">def</h3>
  <select style="display: inline-block; margin-top: 5px" ;>
    <option value="p">Place</option>
    <option value="t">Time</option>
    <option value="f">Fee</option>
  </select>
  <input class="filter" type="checkbox" style="display: inline-block; margin-top: 5px;">
</div>
```